# Numbering Paragraphs using office-js in word

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to get all the paragraphs in a document,

```
var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
context.load(paragraphs);
```

Once you have them how do you apply a custom paragraph numbering?
`setlevelNumbering` seems to possibly be the way but all i get is a bullet point.

Any examples out there ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

This sample add-in uses setLevelNumbering (see line 321 and 409): [Word Add-in MarkdownConversion](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-MarkdownConversion/blob/master/Word-Add-in-JavaScript-MDConversionWeb/Home.js).

Comment: paragraphs.items.forEach(function (paragraph) {

                if (mdListItemParagraph.test(paragraph.text)) {

                    if (!inList) {



                        // This is the start of a list.

                        inList = true;

                        var list = paragraph.startNewList(); in this example for each paragraph a new list is started and the numbering starts at 0 - so if I have 10 paragraphs would they not all end up with the same numbering? can you create a list on the paragraphcollection? , so you end up with 1,2,3,,,etc ?

Comment: @stuart I can't read your comment clearly and it is better to start a new question than to ask a new question in a comment.

Comment: to use setlevelnumbering you have to use a list , the docs say a list is a collection of paragraph objects, a paragraphcollection is also a collection of paragraphs - but to cant use setlevelnumbering on that! i dont see List in the api docs, not under word, not under shared.  anyway if i have a paragraph collection object and iterate thru them, i thought i could start a new list with the first item, then add the remaining paragraph items to that list - all at the same level - then apply the setlevelnumbering to the list and that should number all my paragraphs?

Comment: using your example i was able to apply level numbering to the first paragraph in my document - but that is all :(